# is Generic option -D not supporting in hadoop 0.20.2?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i am trying to set the configuration property from the console using -D generic options.

here is my console input:

```
$ hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.2/gtee.jar dd.MaxTemperature -D file.pattern=2007.* /inputdata /outputdata
```

but i did cross verification from the code by

```
Configuration conf;
System.out.println(conf.get("file.pattern"));
```

results null output.what would be the problem here, why value of the property "file.pattern" not displaying ? Can any one please help me.

Thanks

**EDITED SECTION:**

Driver Code:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
    job.setJobName("MaxTemperature");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), conf);
//  System.out.println(conf.get("file.pattern"));

    if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))) {
        fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
    }

    System.out.println(conf.get("file.pattern"));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(job, RegexExcludePathFilter.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MapMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Mapreducers.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Mapreducers.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int xx = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new MaxTemperature(), args);
    System.exit(xx);
}
```

path filter implementation:

```
public static class RegexExcludePathFilter extends Configured implements
        PathFilter {
        //String pattern = "2007.[0-1]?[0-2].[0-9][0-9].txt" ;
        Configuration conf; 
        Pattern pattern;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(path.toString());
        return m.matches();
    }

    @Override
    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(conf.get("file.pattern"));
        System.out.println(pattern);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm you -D option is supported in the version 20.2 however that requires you to implement the Tool interface to read variables from command line

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration(); //this is the issue
  // When implementing tool use this
   Configuration conf = this.getConf();
```

Comment: i have added the driver code and path filter method for your reference.

Comment: remove this Configuration conf = new Configuration(); and use conf provided by conf class

Answer (score 0):

You are passing it with a space in between, that's not how you should do it. Instead try:

```
-Dfile.pattern=2007.*
```

Comment: yes i tried, but it results the null while i put it into console.

Comment: @adarshaU yeah because nothing parses your arguments, you are missing that code completely.

Comment: is there any alternative ?

Comment: @adarshaU set it in your code or in the core-site.xml.